# How to create an Alfresco custom doclib action to upload a file?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to create a custom doclib action on share to upload a new document.
I have gone through the Alfresco documentation which explains `Send-as-email` custom doclib action. But I am still not sure on the process to create this custom action for uploading a file. Is there an out-of-the-box repository action that I can use?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/alfresco/customizing-the-upload-files-dialog-in-alfresco-share What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I need to create a docLib action which allows the user to upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be multiple ways for achieving this.Best approach for achieving this will be like below as per my perspective.

Follow same steps as explained in `send-as-email` action.Only difference you need to do is customizing form.

You need to customize freemarker template which is referenced in form.In ftl file you can use file chooser and complete the things which you want to achieve.